# Creating a JFrame from java plugin

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am writing a java plugin and need to add a visualizer for that plugin.

Problem is the plugin will be loaded by a game server that call a init function.
I tried to hook a jframe in that init function, but while loading the plugin is giving following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:173)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:546)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:419)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:218)
    at nwn.gs.InitGMAgent.setup(InitGMAgent.java:21)
FATAL ERROR in native method: while executing native code CallStaticVoidMethod(this->cls_initListener, this->jmethodJavaSetup)
```

Aborted (core dumped)

the plugin has main class that I wrote to debug code. When I put the jframe code in main class and run it from console, there were no issue. However, I need to load the Jframe in the init method, called by the server. any help?

my jframe code is very basic right now:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Narrative Viewer");

Container mainContainer = frame.getContentPane();

mainContainer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));

    //add graph visulizer here


frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: *"however, I need to load the Jframe in the init method, called by the server."*  Where exactly should the frame appear?  On the server?  That is what that code would do.  Servers are typically 'headless' and there is no way of changing that.  But then, it is usually pointless to produce a rich client app. for the server technicians in any case.

Comment: Well I am running the plugin in a server, but thats a research project where I need to add some visualization of the data. I am running my server on Ubuntu 12.04 and I have graphics environment installed. Only issue is I run the server in a console, that load the plugin. I tried to run a java executable (which has a main function) from console and it didn't have any issue creating the jframe. The issue is only when I try to create jframe in the init function, which is called by the server

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to answer this questions and maybe you'll decide to redefine your requirements on server.

Are you sure you need to load a Swing component in server where UI system is not always available at all (especially in the world of linux servers, where X11 is usually not installed on servers)?

Where do you want to see this jframe on server?

Maybe you should organize your code so that it won't create a JFrame at all?

Is it possible?

The only thing java offers in this area (as far as I know) is its "headless mode"
In short it allows to run your program on environments where some display device/other "essential devices" are missing.

You might want to read [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: How does 3 questions constitute an answer?

Comment: Well I am running the plugin in a server, but thats a research project where I need to add some visualization of the data.

I am running my server on Ubuntu 12.04 and I have graphics environment installed. Only issue is I run the server in a console, that load the plugin. I tried to run a java executable (which has a main function) from console and it didn't have any issue creating the jframe. The issue is only when I try to create jframe in the init function, which is called by the server.

Comment: yes thats exactly an issue. When you're running in a console (maybe via ssh or something) it "expects" that the console will be able to render the UI you create, but it doesn't. So my advice here is to refactor the UI part. Maybe the server should provide some API for querying it for the data, or maybe it should be configured to send an information to visualization system that can be run as a standalone application. The choice is yours

Comment: I am not using the console through SSL. I am using native Ubuntu console.  Moreover I could create JFrame in the same console from a java executable. My question was if I could create the JFrame from java executables, why it is different when I try to create in a init method of a plugin?